# hyperledger fabric commercial paper buliding problem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to build the hyperledger fabric commercial paper , while I run the node issue.js I am facing the following error,

```
Connect to Fabric gateway.
Use network channel: mychannel.
Use org.papernet.commercialpaper smart contract.
Submit commercial paper issue transaction.
2024-01-07T08:02:17.311Z - error: [DiscoveryResultsProcessor]: parseDiscoveryResults[papercontract] - Channel:mychannel received discovery error:failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"papercontract" > 
Error processing transaction. Error: DiscoveryService: papercontract error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"papercontract" > 
Error: DiscoveryService: papercontract error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"papercontract" > 
    at DiscoveryResultsProcessor.parseDiscoveryResults (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryResultsProcessor.js:31:11)
    at async DiscoveryService.send (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:341:19)
    at async ContractImpl.newDiscoveryService (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/contract.js:281:9)
    at async ContractImpl.getDiscoveryHandler (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/contract.js:258:25)
    at async Transaction.submit (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:236:43)
    at async main (/home/sabiha/fabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/issue.js:69:31)
Disconnect from Fabric gateway.
Issue program complete.
```

how to solve it.
how do i solve the error?